# How to change plymouth theme ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, 19.10, plymouth

I have installed `plymouth-themes` using apt and it also automatically installs `plymouth-theme-spinner`. How can i remove the spinner theme and/or install a new theme?

Answer (score 2):

To install all available themes in the repo

```
sudo apt install plymouth-theme-*
```

For listing and changing plymouth themes

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

After choosing a theme

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

If you can't see it try

```
echo "FRAMEBUFFER=y" | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash && sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```